# Session variable get lost after redirect

Tags: php, symfony

I have an issue with session variable getting lost upon redirecting user to a third party website and then getting back at me. I made a simpler version of the error to make it reproductible:

```
            if($request->getSession()->get('session_variable') == 'made'){
                //I do some stuff           
            }else{
                $request->getSession()->set('session_variable','made');

                $request->getSession()->save();
                //tried adding this but it doesnt change anything 

                $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
                return $this->redirect($actual_link);
            }
```

So this piece of code should, In my understanding get in the else once, set the session variable and then get out of the loop.
The thing is that the code keeps on looping on the else loop forever

I get the request paramter from the webservice:

```
    public function myWebService(Request $request, $otherParam){
...
```

I'm using Symfony 6 and php 8

Strange fact that I can hardly understand: sometimes the problem will not happend. Same initial url

Comment: I would redirect the user to the `https` version before hitting any controller with a `.htaccess`. I guess the problem is that your cookies are set to secure and the `http` version can't access them

Comment: setting cookie_secure to false seem to make this work. Since the third party I'm working with are doing header enchirchment I am kind of forced to use http for this specific pages. What am I risking letting the cookie secure variable to false ?

Comment: The third party is forcing you to use http?  That would set off all kinds of security concerns especially in this day and age.  Maybe you could use the http client to access those pages?  Even doing that would be a concern even if the connection was secured by some other means.

Comment: yes, its a mobile carrier. In some countries they are enriching my pages with MSISDN when the users are browsing in 3/4G, so I can use it to identify if I already know the user or not. And more importantly if the user is browsing from this carrier. the url I call from the page to get the enrichment is HTTP and it wont work if I call it from an HTTPS url. I thinkg I  cannot bypass this. What would cause cookie secure variable to false ?

Comment: If you try with this (to test) `return $this->redirectToRoute('you_toute_name');` instead of your return, does it works or do you still lose the session?